# IP address- is it dangerous for someone to know?

Tags: internet

The last couple days I was talking to someone online, and this person said that my IP address was this and that, out of nowhere... Which was wrong, probably because I was connected to a VPN (not the point) but still, I'm worried now, how can you even check someone's IP address? Is it dangerous? Why would someone do it? To get my location or any other reason?

Comment: Is it dangerous for someone to know your home address?

Answer (score -3):

Actually it is not dangerous on some aspects, your IP address is your basic identity  to your system when connected to internet and if someone knows it then you can be exploited on some basis for some instant of time.
But it is difficult to establish a persistant connection because every time your pc restarts, it gets its new ip address.
So no need to be afraid.

Comment: The line about getting a new IP address every time your PC restarts is overly confident. For a lot of modern internet connections, the IP address for a given connection will remain stable as long as the router is connected, or be entirely static. You certainly can't count on rebooting changing your IP address.

Comment: "if someone knows it then you can be exploited on some basis for some instant of time" is not necessarily true. Whether you can be exploited really depends on whether your internet firewall exposes any ports for inbound  and if the services running on those ports have vulnerabilities to be exploited. And yes, the assumption that your external IP changes frequently is not valid.